# Incremental spend in 6 weeks for two groups using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, increment, cumsum

I have an excel data with the following information,

```
df.head()
   User_id  Group   Week    Spend   Purchases   Group
170309867   Test    2014-10-13  794.66  2   Test-NonRed
57954586    Test    2014-10-13  55.99   1   Test-Red
118068583   Test    2014-10-13  40.87   1   Test-NonRed
516478393   Test    2014-10-13  17.5    2   Test-NonRed
457873235   Test    2014-10-13  20.44   1   Test-Red
```

From the above information, I need to calculate the incremental spend in the six weeks for the total Test group (test-Red and test-NonRed) vs. control. I need it in absolute ($) and % terms.
I have tried pandas as,

```
  df2= df.groupby(by=['Group','Week']).sum().abs().groupby(level=[0]).cumsum()
```

And I have the following result,

```
df2.head()
```

[image]

And then I calculated the sum for each group as,

```
    df2.groupby(by=['group2']).sum()
df2.head()
```

[image]

I would like to have them ( the incremental spend) as an absolute value which I tried by `abs()`, as well as I need it in absolute percentage.Any help would be much appreciated,

The expected results are to calculate the incremental spend in the six weeks for the total Test group (test-Red and test-NonRed) vs. Control. I need it in absolute spend and then its percentage.The incremental spend for the 6 weeks. Something like this,

```
 Group   incremental_spend  incremental_%       
    Control     11450175         #%
    test-NonRed 50288158         #%
    test-Red    12043938         #%
```

So my real questions,
1.  Whether the above-mentioned approach is the right way to calculate incremental spend for Column `Group` in 6 Weeks from column `Week` on `Spend`? 
2. Also, I need all my results in Absolute counts and Absolute %

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the issue is?

Comment: @AndrewL, I have edited my question

Comment: Are you sure you want to be summing up a cumulative sum? That doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are several problems here which make your answer difficult to understand.

#### Vocabulary

- What you describe as "Incremental spend" is just the `sum`.
  What you do in two steps is the sum of the cumulative sum `.cumsum().sum()`, which is not right.
- Also I am not sure whether you need `abs`, which gives the absolute value (`abs(-1)` gives `1`) and will thus only have an effect if there are negative values in your data.
  Unfortunately the sample dataset is not large enough to get a conclusion.

#### Dataset

Your dataset has two columns `Group` with identical names, which is error prone.

#### Missing information

You want to get final values (sums) as a ratio (%), but you do not indicate what is the reference value for this ratio.
Is it the sum of `Spend` for the control group ?

#### Potential solution

```
>>> df  # Sample dataframe with one entry as 'Control' group
Out[]:
     User_id Group        Week   Spend  Purchases      Group.1
0  170309867  Test  2014-10-13  794.66          2  Test-NonRed
1   57954586  Test  2014-10-13   55.99          1     Test-Red
2  118068583  Test  2014-10-13   40.87          1  Test-NonRed
3  516478393  Test  2014-10-13   17.50          2      Control
4  457873235  Test  2014-10-13   20.44          1     Test-Red


df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Group.1').Spend.sum())  # Get 'Spend' sum for each group

>>> df2
Out[]:
              Spend
Group.1
Control       17.50
Test-NonRed  835.53
Test-Red      76.43

control_spend_total = df2.loc['Control'].values  # Get total spend for 'Control' group

>>> control_spend_total
Out[]: array([ 17.5])


df2['Spend_%'] = df2.Spend / control_spend_total * 100  # Add 'Spend_ratio' column

>>> df2
Out[]:
              Spend      Spend_%
Group.1
Control       17.50   100.000000
Test-NonRed  835.53  4774.457143
Test-Red      76.43   436.742857
```

Does it look like what you want?